# Poisson arrivals and exponential inter-arrival times

Tags: matlab, poisson, exponential-distribution

In Matlab, I want generate events that follow Poisson arrivals and the inter-arrival time between events to be exponentially distributed?

Which command should I use ?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/exprnd.html

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have a counting process, {*N(t)*,*t* >= 0}, where *N*(*t*) is the number of events to occur by *t*.

If these events follow a **Poisson Process (PP)** with rate *lambda* then there are a host of properties we get for free. This posts assumes a homogeneous (or stationary) **PP**.  See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/369294/177387) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/369093/177387) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/369298/177387) for the time-dependent case.

Interevent times from a **PP** are Exponentially distributed with rate *lambda*.

**Approach 1:**
1. Generate interevent times
2. Obtain actual event times       <---what you're wanting

```
Rate = 0.75;        % lambda   (events per unit time)
NumEvents = 20;     % number of events to generate

% Approach 1a         requires exprnd function
InterEventTimes = exprnd(1/Rate,NumEvents,1);
EventTimes = cumsum(InterEventTimes);

% Approach 1b         using inverse transform of exponential distribution
fh =@(n) - log(rand(n,1) / Rate;    % inverse transform of exponential distribution
InterEventTimes2 = fh(NumEvents);
EventTimes2 = cumsum(InterEventTimes2);
```

Validation for both of these approaches is [available here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/369294/177387).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether there is a function, or that I am understanding the question correctly.

The formula for event times of a Poisson process is

```
tau=1/lambda*ln(1/r)
```

where `lambda` is the intensity of the process and `r` is a unit uniform distribution, such as the one produced by `rand`.

Comment: That would be the formula for **inter**-event times, and the builtin function should generally be used rather than rolling your own.

Comment: @pjs, if the `exprnd` function isn't available, using the inverse transform of the Exponential would be a good start.  Then `cumsum` would give the event times.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan Using an exponential distribution, whether you use a built-in or roll your own with inversion, gives the times *between* events for a Poisson.  The answer claims the inversion is the formula for event times, which is incorrect.

Comment: @pjs, I don't dispute that. See my answer to verify. My comment was implying that it is ok to use the inverse transform of the Exponential to get the interevent times. From these, `cumsum` gives the event times.  I think we're violently agreeing here.  Merry Christmas.